# Styling Html Widget in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the flutter_html package

I have this in my flutter project, i have been trying to style the line height property of the resulting text rendered in my view and its not working and i dont seem to find a solution anywhere.
Any help will be appreciated
Html(

```
              data: detail.length >= 300 ? detail.substring(0, 300) + " ...": detail.substring(0),
               style: {
                "html":Style(
                 /*  wordSpacing: 3, */
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                 whiteSpace: WhiteSpace.NORMAL
                ),
              },
              )
```

Comment: I am using the flutter_html package

Answer (score 1):

Currently the `Html()` widget from `flutter_html: ^1.x.x` is not supporting line-height property of css.
So you need to use `HtmlWidget()` from `flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.5.x`

```
HtmlWidget(
         htmlData,
         textStyle: TextStyle(height: 1.8)
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension mechanism for achive Your goals:

```
extension ToHtmlStyleExtension on TextStyle {
  FlutterHtml.Style toHtmlStyle() {
    return FlutterHtml.Style(
      color: color,
      fontFamily: fontFamily,
      fontSize: FlutterHtml.FontSize(fontSize),
      fontWeight: fontWeight,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).